# How to read image from s3 bucket for Amazon Rekognition using python?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-rekognition

Hi I am working on a project where I have a source image in s3 bucket and I want to compare it with images in my local computer. I have already set up aws cli. Here is the code. My image is in some bucket 'bx' with name 's.jpg'. Now I want to read it so I called get_object method and used open() to read but it didn't worked.

```
import boto3
import os
if __name__ == "__main__":
    path2 = '/home/vivek/Desktop/tar/'
    t=[j for j in os.listdir(path2)]
    buck=boto3.client('s3')
    obj=buck.get_object(Bucket='bx',Key='s.jpg')
    imageSource=open(obj['Body'],'rb')
    for targetFile in t:
        client=boto3.client('rekognition')
        imageTarget=open(targetFile,'rb')
        response=client.compare_faces(SimilarityThreshold=70,
        SourceImage={'Bytes': imageSource.read()},
        TargetImage={'Bytes': imageTarget.read()})
```

I get an error :

```
vivek@skywalker:~/Desktop/code$ python3 y.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "y.py", line 9, in <module>
    imageSource=open(obj['Body'],'rb')
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not StreamingBody
```

Comment: Why are you getting the object at all? The compare_faces() method allows you to indicate objects that are in S3 using S3Object and setting Bucket='bs' and Name='s.jpg'.

Comment: Oh but I guess that is only in when both source and target are in S3 and you call API from the command line. Can you please write a syntax which i can include in my code. Thanks

Comment: You need to fix the problem in your code with the source image first. Preferably use the aforementioned S3Object solution (instead of downloading the file from S3 and then immediately attempting to upload it to Rekognition). If you must download it (why?) then fix your open() call - you cannot open a StreamingBody. Instead use obj.get()['Body'].read() to get Bytes and pass that into the compare_faces() call as Bytes in TargetImage.